# WinForms Browser Control and the Death of IE

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I was wondering if anyone knows what is going to happen with the win forms browser control in the .net framework after IE 11 support is dropped next month. From my understanding the browser control uses an IE shell, but if IE is no longer supported what will happen? are we just SOL? are the porting it to use Edge? just wondering if anyone has heard, I cant seem to find any info. Thanks!

Comment: "Dropping support" just means they stop releasing updates (security and new features). It doesn't mean that at midnight the application will cease to function at all.

Comment: Please check [Bringing a modern WebView to your .NET WinForms and WPF Apps](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2018/05/09/modern-webview-winforms-wpf-apps/#qwk3GlzPRky2pd3x.97)

Comment: Also, where are you seing that IE11 is End Of Life soon? [Microsoft says "Internet Explorer 11 will be supported for the life of Windows 7, Windows 8.1, and Windows 10."](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/windows/end-of-ie-support). Windows 10 isn't slowing down any time soon, and I don't think there are any plans to make IE 12.

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft is not discontinuing support for IE 11; they're simply not developing another version of IE. According to [Lifecycle FAQ—Internet Explorer and Edge](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17454/lifecycle-faq-internet-explorer):

> *"Internet Explorer 11 is the last major version of Internet Explorer. **Internet Explorer 11 will continue receiving security updates and technical support for the lifecycle of the version of Windows on which it is installed**."*

Therefore, the answer is:

*"The Winforms Browser control will keep working the same way it was before."*

Comment: ...until your OS gets dropped. But at that point, get your clients off of old OSs (if you can).